# Improve description of "comment everywhere" privilege

Tags: feature-request, comments, privileges, help-center

The [*Comment everywhere* privilege](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment) description in many (all?) of the sites currently says (boldface added):

> Please note that you can always comment on your own posts, and **any part of your questions**. However, commenting on **other people's posts** is a privilege gained from earning reputation [...]

The above doesn't make it clear that *any* user can actually add comments *on answers to their questions*. Probably the first boldface phrase was meant to convey that, but it's really confusing that an answer qualifies as a "part of your question", and not as "other people's posts".

So, can it be worded more explicitly? Perhaps something like (the changed parts are in italics)

> Please note that you can always comment on your own posts, and ***on answers to* your questions**. However, commenting on ***other* posts** is a privilege gained from earning reputation [...]

Comment: It may not be clear, but there appear to be 8 types of Posts: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2677/database-schema-documentation-for-the-public-data-dump-and-sede/2678#2678.

Answer (score 9):

What about following version?

> Please note that you can always comment on your own posts, **and on answers to your questions.** However, commenting on **other people's posts (except listed above)** is a privilege gained from earning reputation [...]

Comment: I think it would read a little easier if the second sentence said "However, commenting on **any other posts** is a privilege gained from earning reputation".

Comment: @Rainbacon Maybe post it as an answer, so that people can vote on that proposal too

Answer (score 6):

I would propose a slightly modified version of Qwertiy's

> Please note that you can always comment on **your own posts, and on answers to your questions**. However, commenting on **any other posts** is a privilege gained from earning reputation [...]

Answer (score 1):

My main point for improvement: "Comment everywhere" isn't "everywhere" to a new StackExchange user, or an infrequent user like me.  To me, I thought "everywhere" meant every site.  I suggest "everywhere" is misleading and therefore isn't the correct word.

Too hard as it is (yes, I've now learned about the spam problem), I thought 50 reputation points would at least let me comment EVERYWHERE (on every site).  Apparently "everywhere" actually means everywhere within each one of many sites.  I get around to StackExchange sites infrequently.  I'd be surprised if I ever got 50 reputation points enough to "Comment everywhere", on even one site.

I used a Google search to get answers about 50-reputation commenting that I couldn't easily locate or navigate to on the sites.  It was misleading to me, yet I'm not a newb to the web.  I've been an editor and commenter elsewhere on the web for many years.

Comment: This question is not exactly structured as a question, which I think would get it savaged on other sites.  Or am I suppose to edit this title with only 14 points total on 4 sites?

Comment: But, surprise, as I began an answer to this question, I discovered that Meta will allow Comments with only 5 reputation points.  As a result. is Meta swamped with spam?

Comment: Just previous to answering the question, found out that the StackExchange domains are called "sites", and that apparently, from my recent devices logout dialog, they don't all even have "exchange" in the names ("Superuser"?).

Comment: 1. The question is a question *So, can it be worded more explicitly?* 2. Meta is very small so the value in spamming it is low. It also has lots of high rep users for its size so spam is kept under control.

Answer (score -2):

How about:

> Please note that you can always comment on your own posts, **and on answers to your questions.** However, **commenting when you didn't ask nor answer the question** is a privilege gained from earning reputation [...]